# How can I change URL from $scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-click

I have made access navigation with `$scope` and I used them based on click and I did. I can't set URL in variable accommodate. The correct URL is `http://www.example.com/base/index` or `http://www.example.com/base/thread`, or `http://www.example.com/base/tag`.
But the result is always `http://www.example.com/base/index even thought , I clicked another navigation.

After I search my problem, the answer is make `$routeProvider` and `$location`. Can I use `$scope` and setting URL inside $scope?

**This is my code:**

```
$scope.states = {};
$scope.states.activeItem = 'nav1';

    $scope.items = [{
        id: 'nav1',
        target: 'home',
        title: 'Home',
        icon: 'fa fa-home fa-3x'
    }, {
        id: 'nav2',
        target: 'thread',
        title: 'Thread + Answer',
        icon: 'fa fa-briefcase fa-3x'
    }, {
        id: 'nav3',
        target: 'tag',
        title: 'Tag',
        icon: 'fa fa-briefcase fa-3x'
    },
    {
        id: 'nav4',
        target: 'trending_tag',
        title: 'Trending Tag',
        icon: 'fa fa-briefcase fa-3x'
    },
    {
        id: 'nav5',
        target: 'category',
        title: 'Category',
        icon: 'fa fa-briefcase fa-3x'
    },
    {
        id: 'nav6',
        target: 'user',
        title: 'User',
        icon: 'fa fa-user-circle-o fa-3x'
    }];

    $scope.callToAction = function(actionName){

        if($scope[actionName]){
            $scope[actionName]();
        }else{
            alert("YOUR PAGE NOT FOUND BECAUSE AKU BELUM BUAT PAGE NYA HEHE");
        }
    };
```

By the way, `$scope.items` to execute my navigation.

Comment: As far as it seems you wanted to created a code to show the active URL in the menu or something, right?

Comment: Yes, you right. But im confused to setting url if using that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the URL of your page by using [`$location.url`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

`$location.url('/yourUrl')` will go to `/yourUrl`. You can pass a String as a variable to the function.

Note that you can also access to the current URL with:

```
$scope.currentUrl = $location.url(); // <-- No params
```

---

*Don't forget to [inject](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) `$location` in your service/controller!*

Comment: Can I put $location.url  in $scope.items ? I mean like that {
        id: 'nav1',
        $location.url();
    }

Comment: Is that for a navbar? You can call `$location.url('nav1')` in a `ng-click` if needed.

Comment: Yes for navbar. But its not working. URL is correct but my page not showing

Comment: Im not using routeProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$routeProvider` for navigation.

```
angular.module('FunnyAnt.Examples.Routing')
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'embedded.home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'embedded.about.html',
        controller: 'AboutController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

working [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mtV62/1030/)